# Working with Javascript and Xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

I'm experiencing a less-than-ideal workflow at the moment. Here's the context:

- The project is a hybrid native-web application
- The javascript files are either local (in a .bundle) or on a http server
- We have a lot of javascript tests, most of which are integration tests and must be ran in the simulator.

Although I love javascript and the idea of a reusable application, I must recognize that Xcode doesn't play fair. The main pain is that, quite often and despite the full clean / simu reset, Xcode will need to compile twice before it takes the javascript changes in account.

I've tried to touch all the javascript files before each build (as a script run build phase).
I've also tried to clear the webview cache before each run:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

None of the two suffice.

**tl; dr: What is your workflow when working with javascript files inside an Xcode project, do you like it and how could I improve mine?**